# Python selenium gives data; in Chrome browser

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

Trying to create a webscraper via Selenium. Below code only gives data; in the browser and ends up with error.

```
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

website = ""
path =  "/Users/lilly/Downloads/chromedriver"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)

driver.get(website)

#all_matches_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('')
#all_matches_button.click()

#driver.quit()
```

Chrome browser: Version 104.0.5112.81 (latest)

Chrome driver: 104.0.5112.79 (latest)

Error message in Python:

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist

Tried to reinstall Chrome driver, but not luck. (https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/)

Currently working on my Windows, but above code works on my macbook. I noticed on my Macbook that the version of the Chrome browser and driver are the same (104.0.5112.79).

Also have to close all browser tabs before running the code. otherwise it will result in the below error:

> InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: user data directory is already in use error using --user-data-dir

Also quite annoying..

Thanks.

L.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, you have to provide the file extension. In your Mac, the chrome driver executable file name is `chromedriver`. But for Windows, it is `chromedriver.exe`.
Change your path to the following and it will work. Make sure the executable file path is provided not just the folder.

```py
path =  "/Users/lilly/Downloads/chromedriver.exe"
```

Comment: Tried the above. Still no luck. Message: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist.

Comment: This worked out: options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222") driver = webdriver.Chrome(path, options=options)